Work-around for unexpected user-defined transform behavior in fable?
Q: Is there a good work-around for the following unexpected user-defined transform behavior in fable? Is this a bug?
Following Forecasting Principles and Practice, Ch. 13.3, Ensuring forecasts stay within limits on a dataset, I found strange behavior around user-defined transforms, back transforms, and forecasts. In particular, for the scaled logit transform. See below.
Is there a good hack/fix/work-around for this? I can always manually transform and backtransform the data myself, before passing it to model(). But it'd be nice if someone knew of way to avoid this.
library(fpp3)

y <- c(145.1, 27.3, 37.4, 3.2, 3.8, 106.9, 4.3, 43.2, 16.2, 251.9, 1.1, 20.8, 
       17.7, 47.1, 34.2, 85.3, 61.5, 34.8, 216.3, 28.9, 4.8, 5.6, 104.3, 10.7, 
       120.8, 37.2, 435.5, 22.3, 23.9, 3.6, 10.3, 13.4, 19.9, 4.1, 5.9, 4.1, 
       756.3, 68.5, 218, 32, 227.1, 79.9, 141.2, 24.5, 179.6, 39.3, 391.4, 12.2, 
       9.2, 13.1, 8, 15.9, 2.3, 24.1, 14.7, 1.4, 4.8, 6.6, 7.8, 4.4, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
       0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 9.4, 2.3, 
       30.5, 1.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.8, 2.2, 0.1, 2.7, 0.1, 5.4, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1, 
       0.1, 27.9, 12, 21.8, 5.4, 18217.6, 22806.3, 46311.4, 12808, 10253.8, 
       11275.2, 8353.5, 11929.1, 12147.8, 1385.8, 17915.9, 343, 4152.8, 5520.9)

# upper and lower bounds of data
max(y) # 46311.4
min(y) # 0.1

# construct data
tibble(idx=1:113,y=y) %>% tsibble(index=idx) -> dat

# define scaled logit
# via Forecasting Priniples and Practice, Ch. 13.3, Ensuring forecasts stay
# within limits
# https://otexts.com/fpp3/limits.html
scaled_logit <- function(x, lower = 0, upper = 1) {
  log((x - lower) / (upper - x))
}
inv_scaled_logit <- function(x, lower = 0, upper = 1) {
  (upper - lower) * exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)) + lower
}
my_scaled_logit <- new_transformation(
  scaled_logit, inv_scaled_logit)

# forecasting, setting bounds so that all data between
dat %>%
  model(
    y.lgt.arima=ARIMA(
      my_scaled_logit(y,lower=0,upper=50000)~pdq(d=0)+PDQ(0,1,0,period=54)
      )
    ) ->
  fit

# fits stay within bounds
fit %>% fitted() %>% pull(.fitted) %>% max() # 29475.22
fit %>% fitted() %>% pull(.fitted) %>% min() # 0.1744393

# forecast goes outside of bounds
fit %>% forecast(h=100) -> fcs
fcs %>% pull(.mean) %>% max() # 82827.8
fcs %>% pull(.mean) %>% min() # -119000

fcs %>% autoplot(level=NULL)+autolayer(dat)


UPDATE: Did an extra check to see if differencing, esp., seasonal, was causing the issue. Even without differencing, the issue persists.
# forecasting, setting bounds so that all data between 0 and 50000
# adding a couple models to see if differencing was the problem
dat %>%
  model(
    y.lgt.c.p0q.010=ARIMA(my_scaled_logit(resp(y),lower=0,upper=50000)~pdq(d=0)+PDQ(0,1,0,period=54)),
    y.lgt.c.p1q.000=ARIMA(my_scaled_logit(resp(y),lower=0,upper=50000)~pdq(d=1)+PDQ(0,0,0,period=54)),
    y.lgt.c.p0q.000=ARIMA(my_scaled_logit(resp(y),lower=0,upper=50000)~pdq(d=0)+PDQ(0,0,0,period=54)),
  ) ->
  fit

# fits stay within bounds
fit %>% fitted() %>% slice_min(.fitted, by=.model, with_ties=FALSE)
# # A tsibble: 3 x 3 [1]
# # Key:       .model [3]
# .model            idx .fitted
# <chr>           <int>   <dbl>
# 1 y.lgt.c.p0q.010    65 0.00386
# 2 y.lgt.c.p1q.000    69 0.100  
# 3 y.lgt.c.p0q.000    63 0.132  

fit %>% fitted() %>% slice_max(.fitted, by=.model, with_ties=FALSE)
# # A tsibble: 3 x 3 [1]
# # Key:       .model [3]
# .model            idx .fitted
# <chr>           <int>   <dbl>
# 1 y.lgt.c.p0q.010   104  28844.
# 2 y.lgt.c.p1q.000   103  38574.
# 3 y.lgt.c.p0q.000   103  38328.

# forecast goes outside of bounds for D=1 model
fit %>% forecast(h=100) -> fcs

fcs %>% slice_min(.mean, by=.model, with_ties=FALSE)
# # A fable: 3 x 4 [1]
# # Key:     .model [3]
# .model            idx               y   .mean
# <chr>           <dbl>          <dist>   <dbl>
# 1 y.lgt.c.p0q.010   209   t(N(0.3, 61)) -27028.
# 2 y.lgt.c.p1q.000   114 t(N(-2.2, 3.7))  11246.
# 3 y.lgt.c.p0q.000   114 t(N(-2.2, 3.7))  11623.

fcs %>% slice_max(.mean, by=.model, with_ties=FALSE)
# # A fable: 3 x 4 [1]
# # Key:     .model [3]
# .model            idx               y   .mean
# <chr>           <dbl>          <dist>   <dbl>
# 1 y.lgt.c.p0q.010   212 t(N(-0.96, 61)) 149507.
# 2 y.lgt.c.p1q.000   213 t(N(-2.2, 168)) 308049.
# 3 y.lgt.c.p0q.000   175  t(N(-0.9, 50)) 123604.

UPDATE: new tests based on observations of @Seth in comments. Medians of the distribution respect bounds of the transformation while means do not.
# trying another test, based on observation of @Seth in comments
# operate on the distribution itself, `y`, see what does/doesn't preserve bounds
fcs %>% mutate(avg=mean(y), med=median(y)) -> fcs.enh

# `median(y)` respects lower bound while `mean(y)` does not
fcs.enh %>%  as_tibble() %>%
  summarise(
    across(c(avg, med, y, .mean), min),
    .by=.model
    ) 
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
# .model              avg      med               y   .mean
# <chr>             <dbl>    <dbl>          <dist>   <dbl>
# 1 y.lgt.c.p0q.010 -27028.    0.196 t(N(-3.4, 7.7)) -27028.
# 2 y.lgt.c.p1q.000  11246. 4813.    t(N(-2.2, 3.7))  11246.
# 3 y.lgt.c.p0q.000  11623. 5020.    t(N(-2.2, 3.7))  11623.

# `median(y)` respects upper bound while `mean(y)` does not
fcs.enh %>%  as_tibble() %>%
  summarise(
    across(c(avg, med, y, .mean), max),
    .by=.model
  ) 
# # A tibble: 3 × 5
# .model              avg    med               y   .mean
# <chr>             <dbl>  <dbl>          <dist>   <dbl>
# 1 y.lgt.c.p0q.010 149507. 47583. t(N(-0.86, 61)) 149507.
# 2 y.lgt.c.p1q.000 308049.  5146. t(N(-2.2, 168)) 308049.
# 3 y.lgt.c.p0q.000 123604. 18581. t(N(-0.53, 57)) 123604.


If you examine the prediction intervals (remove level=NULL from the autoplot function), you'll see they are constrained within the limits you set. I do not know if the expected behavior should extend to the mean, but it does appear to correctly transform and backtransform to determine the predictions. May be worth raising as an issue on the fabletools repo.

@Seth. Good eye. I just added an additional test, inspired by your observation, and found that medians of the distribution preserve bounds while means do not.
